Karate project hangs on reading karate-config.js
Attempting to run a Karate-maven project via Terminal, but sucks on reading karate-config.js
I attempt to run a Karate-maven project via Terminal (MacOS). The run sucks on the step of reading karate-config.js
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.illumina.solEn.webSolutions.testRunner
12:18:07.700 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.Runner - using system property 'karate.env': adaptce_local
12:18:07.945 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js

The properties and versions are
<properties>      
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version> 
        <karate.version>1.2.0</karate.version>
  </properties>

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

You probably ran into this known problem with Karate version <= 1.4.1 and Java 22.
Recommend you upgrade to Karate 1.5.0.
